# Hiding Group resource column in mvc kendo ui scheduler

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

This is my schedule code and is grouped by providers

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<LTC_TABXML.Entity.Projection>()
      .Name("AppointmentDataScheduler")
      .Date(DateTime.Now)
      .ShowWorkHours(true)
      .AllDaySlot(false)
      .EventTemplateId("customAllDayTemplate")
      .Views(views => views.DayView(dayview => dayview.Selected(true)))
      .Group(group => group.Resources("Providers"))
      .Resources(resource => resource.Add(m => m.ProviderID)
      .Title("Company")
      .Name("Providers")
      .DataTextField("ProviderName")
      .DataValueField("ID")
      .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetProvider", "Home")))
      ).Editable(false)
       .Height(800)
       .BindTo(Model))
```

This is my multi select on which I want to hide group column but it is only hiding the event in schedule

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
              .Name("Provider")
              .Placeholder("Select Providers...")
              .DataTextField("ProviderName")
              .DataValueField("ID")
              .Events(e => e.Change("Change").Select("Select")
  ).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetProvider", "Home"))))
```

> This the script i called

'

```
function Select(e) {




};

function Change(e) {
    var value = this.value();
    var scheduler = $("#AppointmentDataScheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler.dataSource.filter({
        operator: function (task) {
            return $.inArray(task.ProviderID, value) >= 0;
        }
    });
```

'

Comment: atleast format your question properly and what is your query?

Comment: Hi Bhushan , i want to hide groups resources column in schduler, on the selection of multiselect items

Comment: http://jsbin.com/eKIrusi/1/edit?html,js,output 

like this in MVC but my groups are not hiding when i select the any provider